# Is dualism unlikely because the mind is inextricable in its activity from matter?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, mind-body, dualism

I've been thinking about dualism lately, but one thing that deals a pretty strong blow to this view in my mind is that it implies that the mind can exist apart from physical reality (an immaterial mind or soul, say, that floats out of the body at death).

But isn't a mind, in all of its activity and experience, fully connected to the physical world?

First, any sense perception (which is an integral part of the immediate conscious experience of a mind) is inseparable from some physical organ. Seeing requires an eye, it also requires light to reflect off of physical objects and so on. Thus, sight, sound, smell and all other senses appear incompatible with the experience of some immaterial mind.

Second, even abstract thoughts, intentions, beliefs and so on reduce to some physical structures and events. Thoughts that manifest as language are just examples of sounds and visual symbols that come from the physical world. In other words, take away the senses, and there isn't much consciousness to be had.

Is this kind of objection raised against dualism? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Only *substance* dualism allows mind to exist apart from matter, and almost nobody subscribes to it nowadays. The currently popular form is [property dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_dualism) which does not allow mind to exist apart from matter, but does allow mental properties of matter that are irreducible to physical ones. But not even physicalists would say that "thoughts are just sounds and visual symbols", this quickly leads to nonsense. They would only say that thoughts have a material base and can be represented by sounds and visual symbols, not that they *are* them.

Comment: The question is tricky because of all the assumptions. Certainly seeing requires an eye but an eye is not enough for seeing. An eye does not see anything and so there is something more than the physical eye at work. Your statement that when we take away the senses there 'isn't much consciousness to be had' is a conjecture and not something you have verified. Those who do the experiments report a very different result. . .

Comment: Dualism in the sense that there are 2 kinds of entity, the mind and the body(brain), that function separately and independently of each other are not support by any evidence. But information, which is neither matter, energy, force, or other conventional physical entities, can provide the basis for mental substance, and some recent theories (e.g., [1](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/knowledge/identity_theory.html),[2](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/knowledge/emergent_dualism.html),[3](https://mindtheory.net)) assert that the mind is a kind of information entity.

Comment: Because information is categorically different from conventional physical entities (mass, energy, forces, etc.), dualism in the sense that there are two basically different entities in this universe is support by this assertion. But these two kinds of entities must exist and function unitedly as one; this assertion doesn’t support dualism in the sense that there are two basically different entities that function separately or can exist separately from each other in this universe.

Comment: @user287279 I know nowadays Tononi's integrated information theory framework under phenomenology is used a lot to try to define consciousness in the physicalism spirit. But current boolean logic of information can be reduced to its analogue open/close gate mechanical system, so in this sense what's information really different from other mechanical/physical quantities used to study consciousness before?

Comment: @DoubleKnot  The entire analogue open/close gate mechanical system is acturally a kind of information system too because it has a information system as its part. The said mechanical system is consisted of two categorically different systems coexisting inseperably from each other: the overt mechanical system, composed of all the hardware, and the intangible information system, comprising all the system’s information. In fact, everything, including the rocks, trees, stars, etc., is like this – consisted of the two systems, coexisting inseperably from each other.

Comment: It’s only that in some systems, like those of the rocks or other non-living things, the information part is negligible in general circumstances.

You can have more detailed discussion of this kind of idea at this web page: [2.3. Physicalism and dualism](https://mindtheory.net/chapter-2/) on [this website](https://mindtheory.net/)

Comment: @user287279 thx for ur reference. I no doubt accept some primitive aspects on consciousness can be fully explained using IIT like theory such as perception, reasoning. However per my idealism, the key part of our mind (self-awareness, vital soul) seems only exists as a simple substance rejecting any reduction where our true abstract understanding like math occurs since it needs exactness, not likeness. Physicalism can only provide likeness. Leibniz Mill Argument (or Searle's Chinese Room Argument) came to my mind immediately, how your mechanical/informational system can explain Mill Argument?

Comment: ... from my own perspective, the often-heard difference between knowing vs true understanding is the former happens in likeness from outside perceived physical world via sense organs, while the latter occurs in exactness from inside Platonic ideal realm via the vital single soul which is exactly same for everyone. Since the source soul is exactly same, that's why we can all agree and thus truly understand common ideal math theorems. Otherwise our qualia from the senses' likeness never match, then we may never agree on any thing. In short, any idea can only be born in an ideal (soul)...

Comment: @DoubleKnot It’s difficult to explain it here because of the limited space. Shortly, Leibniz only looked at the mill’s mechanical parts that push and pull each other; he overlooked the non-material, information part that exists in every part of the mill and that influences and affects other parts and enables the mill to work. For example, a cogwheel that’s rotating clockwise has information to the mill’s system different from a cogwheel that’s rotating anti-clockwise; they thus affect the mill differently.

Comment: Our perception, qualia, consciousness, and mind reside in the information part, not the mechanical part, of the mill. Again, more detailed discussion of this idea can be found in the above references.

Comment: thx for ur elaboration, and u seem subscribing to modern property/mode-dualism or just phenomenology, which one more fit to u? (I feel u are more incline to the former) I'll review those references...

Comment: I reviewed ur whole theory up to chapter10, and I like ur proposed ARAS alert network along with the main neural processing network and its application to explain consciousness during sleep or other similar cases. And ur main thesis seems consciousness can be "reduced" to "a special kind of reentrant signaling state". My main argument is why such state only can be found in neuron not electric circuit? And more importantly unless u can describe such "reentrant " state in detail and quantify like IIT, it still sounds like a metaphysical speculation/belief about such a possible state existence...

Comment: ...another critique is u claimed different qualia must come from different neural processes.  But sometimes even same person sees same word will cause 2 or many more different qualia to flash in mind. For example when I see number 2, I may visualize 2 apple, 2 dollars, or double an existing action, or 3-1, or 1+1, etc. Per ur theory, all these different qualia must come from different informational state of neural processes, but if so, besides same outside "2", my brain must have some other variables to add to these different states, then it seems impossible to apply even for a simple case...

Comment: @user287279 any feedback or comment for my above critiques after reviewing your reference?

Comment: @DoubleKnot Thank you for the comment. I'm sorry for replying late; I haven't visited this website for several days because I'm being tied up with some work. Your comments require long answers that cannot be given here. Could you please give your email that's convenient for long discussion? I'll give the feedback there. However, it'll take me almost another week before I'll be free for any serious, long discussion again. But I promise when I'm free, I'll discuss with you there.

Comment: @user287279 I didn't find a way to email u directly thru stackexchange and not comfortable to disclose here. Can u just create a chat room or email me first? Thx.

Comment: @DoubleKnot I cannot email you first 'cos I don't know your email. You don't have to use your regular or your personal email - you can just create a new one just for chatting with me or other people also. When you get a suitable email, you can contact me at DiscussionMS@gmail.com .

Comment: @user287279 thx for ur info, I've sent one to u.